# Compare the two columns of the dataframe and create a new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am totally new to the `pandas and python.` Here I am trying to compare the columns of the dataframe , my dataframe is like,

```
Document_ID  offset  JAPE      RFC      MANUAL
    0        0      2000       2000    2000
    0        7      2000       2000    2000
    0        16     51200       0      51200
    0        27     51200       0      51200
    0        36     51200       0      51200
    1        0      2000       2000    2000
    1        3      2000       0       2000
    1        4      2200       2200    2200
```

Now, what I am trying to do is  , I am trying to compare the

```
JAPE column with the manual column
RFC column with the manual column
```

Now, Here I tried using the `compare [JAPE] == compare[MANUAL]`  But then I come to know that there is a bit diff between data.

SO , I now am trying with the `offset` column,

like   `for offset 0 of document_ID 0 compare JAPE and MANUAL` If both are equal then I am trying to add new column `JAPE_MANUAL` `true or false or 0 or 1`.

So in this way I am trying to do it using the offsets only .

Can any one help me or give some hints about this ? Thanks

Expected output -

```
 Document_ID     offset  JAPE      RFC      MANUAL  JAPE_MANUAL
        0        0      2000       2000    2000          1
        0        7      2000       2000    2000          1
        0        16     51200       0      51200         1 
        0        27     51200       0      51200          1
        0        36     51200       0      51200         1
        1        0      2000       2000    2000          1
        1        3      2000       0       2000          1
        1        4      2200       2200    2400          0
```

This on the basisof the offset .

Comment: post your expected output

Comment: I have just updated the expected output

Comment: so you want to compare JAPE and MANUAL?

Comment: yes but on the basis of offsets as I said in the question and also the document ID as well

Comment: is my code working fine?

Comment: Yes this is working . I have to check it manually So I asked.

Comment: ok please upvote and approve the answer if it is worked for you

Comment: I have another question not a big one ,   I have a  cols = [100, 200, 2000] array, I am trying to add 0 in the JAPE column if that column does not have the value from my array.  so JAPE column will be for e.g 51200 will become 0.

Comment: So, I tried with isin but no luck. can u give a bit help here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201261/discussion-between-pyd-and-ganesh-kaspate).

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, particularly the part about the `offset` column. Can you provide a bit more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You need `np.where`.

```
import numpy as np
df["JAPE_MANUAL"] = np.where(df['JAPE'] == df['MANUAL'],1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use numpy, or anything else.

```py
df["JAPE_MANUAL"] = df["JAPE'] == df["MANUAL"]
```

Answer (score -1):

generally to form a new column (made by 1 or 0 but you can easily generalie) based on other column values you could use the following

```
df['newColumn']=df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['column1']==x['column2'] else 0, axis=1)
```

hope it is clear the idea behind and you can tune as you need in your specific problem

regards,